# corecursive Agda functions without sized types

Tags: agda, termination, coinduction

I've been doing some experiments with the "old" and "new" ways of dealing with coinduction in Agda, but I think I'm still missing some important facts about the behavior of Agda's termination checking of corecursive functions when `Size` is **not** used.

As an example, consider the following definitions of `Stream` and `repeat`:

```
data    Stream (A : Set) : Set
record ∞Stream (A : Set) : Set where
  coinductive
  field force : Stream A
open ∞Stream

data Stream A where
  cons : A -> ∞Stream A -> Stream A

repeat : ∀{A} -> A -> ∞Stream A
force (repeat x) = cons x (repeat x)
```

Roughly speaking, the coinductive record type `∞Stream` is a specialized `Thunk` for streams. I've seen similar definitions in quite a few Agda formalizations, although they're usually refined a `Size` for better precision. Anyway, the above definition of `repeat` is accepted by Agda without any `Size` annotations.

The problem is when I try to factor out the `∞Stream` record into a `Thunk`, so that I can reuse `Thunk` elsewhere for defining other potentially infinite data types:

```
record Thunk (A : Set) : Set where
  coinductive
  field force : A
open Thunk

data Stream (A : Set) : Set where
  cons : A -> Thunk (Stream A) -> Stream A

repeat : ∀{A} -> A -> Thunk (Stream A)
force (repeat x) = cons x (repeat x)
```

Note that:

- the code for `repeat` is exactly the same in the two cases,
- in each case the recursive call of `repeat` is found immediately below the constructor `cons`,
- in each case `repeat` produces a value of a coinductive record type,

and yet Agda accepts the first definition of `repeat` but rejects the second one (*Termination checking failed for the following functions: repeat*).

I'm aware that using the sized `Thunk` in the standard library the second version can be amended so that it is accepted by Agda. Nonetheless, I'd like to understand what makes the first version above so different from the second one that it passes the termination checker. They look basically the same to me.

Thanks!